# How to use QTest::mouseClick with QAction

Tags: qt, qmenu, qtestlib, qaction

I'm very new to Qt, and I need to simulate a click using the `QTest` Namespace and `QTest::mouseClick`. My problem is I would like to click a `QMenu` entry, defined as a `QAction`, but the `mouseClick` function doesn't allow me to pass this as an argument (only `QWidgets` or `QWindows`).

What could I do here?

Answer (score 4):

You may use another way such direct triggers of your `QAction's` as far as you have them:

```
qAction->trigger();
```

This should have the same impact as mouse clicks in testing purposes.

Comment: It does not completely have the same impact. You will need to manually close the menu afterwards, as the click is handled in QMenu itself.

Answer (score 0):

A `QAction` doesn't have any UI itself, so it can't be clicked.

It can, however, be plugged into several UI components, e.g. in a `QMenu` or a `QToolBar`, which can be clicked.

So if your tests needs to simulate some user interaction, you simulate it with the UI portion created for the action, e.g. the respective tool button on the toolbar, or entry in a menu

Comment: Where can I find a sample for clicking menu and then menu item?